# How to replace the second occurrence of a character in powershell?

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm really struggling with a task that is probably easier than I image it.

I have a file with a lot of lines:

e.g.

```
"numbers TG alongstring" 
"numbers 100 alongstring" 
"numbers 120 alongstring" 
"numbers AF alongstring" 
"numbers 123 alongstring"
```

I want to replace the second occurrence of   (space) with    (two spaces) so that the longstrings line up with each other.
The strings that are 2 characters long are always numbers.

Something like this:

```
"numbers TG  alongstring" 
"numbers 100 alongstring" 
"numbers 120 alongstring" 
"numbers AF  alongstring" 
"numbers 123 alongstring"
```

A thing to note is that the numbers at the beginning are unique along 4000 lines and the longstrings are also not the same length.

What I have so far:

```
foreach ($Line in $file) {
if ($Line[10] -eq " ") {
    $Line.Replace(" ", "  ")
    
    }

}
```

[10] is the index of the space I want to replace.

This replaces all the single spaces with double spaces
I tried a lot of things but haven't had any luck so far.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is your end goal? Is it to lineup the strings or to replace the second space with double space?

Comment: can you include an original sample string?

Comment: Replace the second space with double spaces so that the strings line up. So both :-)

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/sHgqry/2

Comment: @VishalSingh Sorry it is my companies confidential information. I tried to illustrate it as good as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Among other solutions you could use

```
^((?:[^\n ]* (?! )){2})
```

And replace this with `$1` .
See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/sHgqry/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Replace `(?m)(^[^\n\r ]* [^\n\r ]{2})`  (it contains a trailing space) with `$1`   (it contains a double trailing space).

This regex replaces the second single-space occurrence with a double space only if it is preceded by two non-space characters.

- `(?m)` is the multiline flag
- `^` matches the beginning of the line (because of `(?m)`, otherwise it would metche the very beginning of the string)
- `[^\n\r ]*` matches zero or more characters that are neither a space nor a new line
- `[^\n\r ]{2}` matches exactly two characters that are neither a space nor a new line
- `(...)` is a capturing group, and you refer to it with `$1`

See a demo [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fm%29%28%5e%5b%5e%5cn%5cr+%5d*+%5b%5e%5cn%5cr+%5d%7b2%7d%29+&i=%22numbers+TG+alongstring%22+%0d%0a%22numbers+100+alongstring%22+%0d%0a%22numbers+120+alongstring%22+%0d%0a%22numbers+AF+alongstring%22+%0d%0a%22numbers+123+alongstring%22+&r=%241++).

Comment: I forgot to mention that the the strings that are 2 characters long aren't numbers.

Comment: $Line.Replace('(?m)(^[^ ]* [^ ]{2}) ',"$1  ") am I doing that right because it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @whonnock It seems you're calling the [`String.Replace()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, not [`Regex.Replace()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Try with `$Line -replace '(?m)(^[^ ]* [^ ]{2}) ','$1  '`.

Answer (score 0):

Try testing the `.LastIndexOf( ' ' )` return. if the last index of space is 10 you know you are missing a space.  Then you can use the `.Insert()` method to add it in the same position.

Maybe something like:

```
foreach ($Line in $file) {
    if ($Line.LastindexOf( ' ' ) -eq 10 ) {
        $Line.Insert( 10, ' '  )
        }
    }
```

Comment: There are actually more white spaces in that line, I just didn't include them for readability's sake.

Comment: OK so you can't use the `LastIndexOf()`; are the fields in the demo always the first 3.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work and you should be able to come up with a generalized pattern for a match criteria.

```
Get-Content $file | Foreach-Object {
    # matches <nonspaces><space><nonspaces><spaces><rest of string>
    if ($_ -match '^([^ ]+ \S+ +)(.*)$') {
        # $matches.1 is everything matching in the first ()
        # $matches.2 is everything matching in the second ()
        # Assumes alongstring desirably lines up at position 13 starting from 0. Change 13 to the appropriate number if necessary
        ($matches.1).PadRight(13,' ') + $matches.2
    } else {
        $_ 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution splits each line into an array, which then lets you customize the padding for each element:

```
$separator = ' '
$padfile =
   ForEach ($line in $file) {
      $elements = $line -Split $separator
      $elements[0].PadLeft(7), $elements[1].PadRight(3), $elements[2] -Join $separator
   }
```

You can adjust as necessary.